# When to close custom build jQuery dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a very simple dropdown using a `<div>` (parent), `<span>` (current selection) and `<ul>` (options).
It works fine. What I now want to do is if the user clicks anywhere on the page, have it close, like a "real" `<select>` element.

What I do now is this:

```
$(document).delegate('body','click',function(){
   if(isExpanded){close();}
});
```

And it works. What I am worried about is performance. Is it wise to listen for click events on the document node? Is there a better way?

Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK clicks wouldn't hit performance ,, mousemove would definitely.
So there is no problem with your code. But I hope some genius could improve the method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also make use of the `blur` event. While your elements don't support it by default, adding `tabindex=...` makes them fire the `blur` event: http://jsfiddle.net/UgSTa/.

HTML:

```
<div tabindex="1">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li><span>3</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('div').blur(function(){alert(1)})
```

Comment: That's very helpful, I didn't know that. But it isn't what I was asking so I cannot mark it as correct. :) Thanks though.

Comment: @Francisc: I'm sorry but in what way would it not work for you? As soon as the user clicks anywhere else on the page, the `blur` event will fire and you can close the dropdown there.

Comment: Aaa, I understand what you mean now, sorry. That's actually very clever. Any idea what the browser support for this is?

Comment: @Francisc: I can confirm the fiddle works on IE7,8,9, Opera 11, Firefox 6, Chrome 12 and Safari 5. However some show a border around the element with `tabindex` enabled.

Comment: That can be removed with `outline:none;` I believe. Thank you very much, pimvdb.